# How to concatenate sentences from json file to be one text?

Tags: python, json, concatenation

The json file has the structure like this:

```
{"text":"I","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}}
{"text":"love","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}}
{"text":"Coca-cola.","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}}
{"text":"He","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}}
{"text":"loves","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}}
{"text":"Pepsi.","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}}
```

I want to concatenate sentences that belong to the same paper (paper_id) that in the end to have:

```
{"text":"I love Coca-cola. ","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}}
{"text":"He loves Pepsi.","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}}
```

Any ideas how to tackle this?
I stuck in iterating over those nested dictionaries.

Loaded data into list

```
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('datafile_path', 'r')]
for sentence in data:
    for key,dict_n in sentence.items():
        for key2,value in dict_n.items():
            print(value)
```

this throws error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: So you have a file that have a json per line?

Comment: yes, exactly. As I described above. There are actually sentences in texts but to be more clear I ha=gave example of words.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: can you post your attempt at solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the Id's like this:

```
def getIds(data):
    ids = []
    for i in data:
        if i['meta']['paper_id'] not in ids:
            ids.append(i['meta']['paper_id'])
return ids
```

and then you iterate through the list:

```
concatenate_sentence = {"text":"","meta":{"paper_id":"","title":""}}
for id in paper_ids:
    for sentence in data_list:
        if sentence['meta']['paper_id'] == id:
            concatenate_sentence['text'] += sentence['text'] + ' '
            concatenate_sentence['meta']['paper_id'] = id
            concatenate_sentence['meta']['title'] = sentence['meta']['title']

    new_data.append(concatenate_sentence)     
    concatenate_sentence = {"text":"","meta":{"paper_id":"","title":""}}   

 print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'text': 'I love Coca-cola. ', 'meta': {'paper_id': 'cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83', 'title': 'title1'}}, {'text': 'He loves Pepsi. ', 'meta': {'paper_id': '0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3', 'title': 'title2'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append your json into 1 list like:

```
     a=[{"text":"I","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}},
       {"text":"love","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}},
       {"text":"Coca-cola.","meta":{"paper_id":"cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83","title":"title1"}},
       {"text":"He","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}},
       {"text":"loves","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}},
       {"text":"Pepsi.","meta":{"paper_id":"0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3","title":"title2"}}]
```

And, then, convert it into dataframe

```
df = pd. DataFrame.from_dict(a)
df["meta"].apply(pd.Series)
df=pd.concat([df, df['meta'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df1=df.groupby('paper_id')['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
df=df.drop(['text',"meta"], axis=1)
df=df.drop_duplicates("paper_id")
df1=df1.merge(df,how="inner",on="paper_id")
print(df1)
```

Output will be required dataframe, then you can convert it into any required datatype: dictionary, array, anything

```
paper_id    text    title
0   0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3    He loves Pepsi.     title2
1   cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83    I love Coca-cola.   title1
```

Further, reqd_list of dictionaries can be made like this,

```
reqd_list_dict=[]
values = df1.iloc[:,:].values
for i in values:
    temp ={}
    temp["text"] = i[1]
    temp["meta"] = {"paper_id":i[0],"title":i[2]}
    reqd_list_dict.append(temp)
print(reqd_list_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'meta': {'paper_id': '0f3402fa5b44e121d410ec73dfc21937074e5fa3', 'title': 'title2'},'text': 'He loves Pepsi.'},
{'meta': {'paper_id': 'cadf94cda790ae1bd90c32fbe441bb68a8637d83', 'title': 'title1'},'text': 'I love Coca-cola.'}]
```